# Fix error: taking address of temporary without changing codes

Tags: c++

I'm switching from old gcc(3.x) to 4.9.2 and I have some compile issue:

```
if (ROWID_IS_NULL(&pSumItem->getRowId()))
```

`getRowId()` is defined as:

```
rowid_t SumItem::getRowId()
{
    return row_id;
}
```

macro is defined as:

```
#define ROWID_IS_NULL(a) \
    ((a)->key == 0 && (a)->ip_addr == 0)
```

The new code already uses operator overloading to do the calculation, but there still remains a lot of the old code using the non-standard technique. Is it possible to fix this problem without changing the codes?

Error message:

> error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]

Edit : meaning of do not changing the codes

I want to keep this line work

```
if (ROWID_IS_NULL(&pSumItem->getRowId()))
```

Comment: Well, as the error suggests (although I wouldn't blame you for not interpreting it that way), `-fpermissive`, but it's not the greatest option for code safety.

Comment: @chris thanks, but I do not want to use that flag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how far you want to take the "without changing the codes" part. Clearly, whatever fix is applied changes them in some way.

This would be the simple fix, methinks:

```
static inline bool ROWID_IS_NULL(const rowid_t &id) {
    return(id.key == 0 && id.ip_addr == 0);
}
```

Admittedly, though, that would require you to remove the explicit `&` operator in the calls to `ROWID_IS_NULL`.

Comment: In other words, it is not possible to fix this issue safely without changing the codes?

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "without changing the codes"? Clearly, you can't fix it without changing *something*, at least, no?